Как ускорить разбор XML файла?
Необходимо прочитать и разобрать структуру больших фалов XML. Понял что где-то есть проблема в производительности, но не могу понять где именно и как исправить. Когда запускаю скрипт, то ни процессор ни HDD практически не задействуются. HDD практически нулевая загрузка, память тоже не отъедается и не заканчивается. Получается скрипт работает не на полную мощность ресурсов ПК.
Для примера файл размером 1.01Gb с 3 876 111 строк, обрабатывается за 85с на моей конфигурации(i5-6500, RAM 16GB,HDD 2Tb,PHP 8.3.2)
<?php
$log= 'D:\web\test\Apache24\htdocs\multiLoadXML\log_xml_load_gar.log';  
$full_dir='D:\gar\gar_xml\23\AS_HOUSES_20240418_13ca2188-7aa9-461c-bee8-e770d7eda013.XML';
$start = microtime(true);     
if($fp=fopen($log,'w+')){
    fwrite($fp,"Запись начата в - ".date("d-m-Y h:i:s")."\r\n");
    fclose($fp);      
}   
$origin_filds=array(
    'ID'=>null,
    'OBJECTID'=>null,
    'OBJECTGUID'=>null,
    'CHANGEID'=>null,
    'HOUSENUM'=>null,
    'ADDNUM1'=>null,
    'ADDNUM2'=>null,
    'HOUSETYPE'=>null,
    'ADDTYPE1'=>null,
    'ADDTYPE2'=>null,
    'OPERTYPEID'=>null,
    'PREVID'=>null,
    'NEXTID'=>null,
    'UPDATEDATE'=>null,
    'STARTDATE'=>null,
    'ENDDATE'=>null,
    'ISACTUAL'=>null,
    'ISACTIVE'=>null         
);
$teg='HOUSE';
$ins_rows=0;
$z = new XMLReader;
$z->open($full_dir);       
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$z->read(); 
while ($z->read()&&$z->name==$teg)
{             
    $node = simplexml_import_dom($doc->importNode($z->expand(), true));
    $atts_object = $node->attributes();
    $atts_array = (array) $atts_object;
    $atts_array = $atts_array['@attributes'];
    $temp_arr=array_merge($origin_filds,$atts_array);
    $ins_rows++;           
}
$z->close();        
$time = microtime(true) - $start;
echo 'Строк: '.$ins_rows."\r\n";
echo $time.' сек.'."\r\n";
if($fp=fopen($log,'a')){
    fwrite($fp,$time.' сек.'."\r\n");
    fwrite($fp,'Обработано '.$ins_rows." строк \r\n");
    fclose($fp);  
}
               

Вывод:
Строк: 3876111
85.836812019348 сек.


И где проблема в производительности?

Я не спец в PHP, но вижу expand(), который создаёт DOM, и simplexml_import_dom, который тоже создаёт DOM. Зачем двойная обработка? По-моему, нужно оставить что-то одно.

А ещё лучше полностью избавиться от DOM и использовать только потоковый XMLReader.

Переписал на XMLReader, уменьшилось до 68с. Скрипт загружает процессор только на 30%, HDD и RAM практически не работают, не могу понять что нужно сделать чтобы использовать максимум ресурсов и быстрее всё обработать.

Дальше наверно только распараллеливание поможет.

Для сравнения, аналогичный код, но написанный на GO, выполняется на 30% быстрее, но загружает процессор на 40-70%, отъедает во время выполнения от 6 до 8Гб памяти и постоянно использует HDD(читает информацию со скоростью 15-20Мб/с)

Я много работал с XML на разных языках (C++, Java, C#) и могу сказать, что производительность разных XML-парсеров в одном и том же языке различается на порядок.

Возможно есть способ ещё ускорить процесс парсинга XML(может настройками самого PHP, тюнинг php.ini), но на данный момент самый быстрый способ найденный мной использование XMLReader без использования dom:
$start = microtime(true); 
$reader = new XMLReader();
if (!$reader->open('D:\gar\gar_xml\23\AS_HOUSES_20240418_13ca2188-7aa9-461c-bee8-e770d7eda013.XML')) {
    die("Failed to open '*.xml'");
}
$origin_filds=array(
    'ID'=>null,
    'OBJECTID'=>null,
    'OBJECTGUID'=>null,
    'CHANGEID'=>null,
    'HOUSENUM'=>null,
    'ADDNUM1'=>null,
    'ADDNUM2'=>null,
    'HOUSETYPE'=>null,
    'ADDTYPE1'=>null,
    'ADDTYPE2'=>null,
    'OPERTYPEID'=>null,
    'PREVID'=>null,
    'NEXTID'=>null,
    'UPDATEDATE'=>null,
    'STARTDATE'=>null,
    'ENDDATE'=>null,
    'ISACTUAL'=>null,
    'ISACTIVE'=>null         
);
$row=0;
while($reader->read()) {
    if ($reader->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT && $reader->name == 'HOUSE') {
        foreach($origin_filds as $key => $value){
            $temp_arr[$key] = $reader->getAttribute($key);
        }        
    }
    $row++;
}
$time = microtime(true) - $start;
echo $time.' сек.'."\r\n";
echo 'Строк: '.$row."\r\n";
$reader->close();


php 8.3.8 + сброс настроек php.ini по умолчанию + выше написанный код сократили время вдвое. Теперь скрипт парсит этот же файл за 30с
...\php-8.3.8\php.exe .\testReadXML.php
Строк: 3876111
30.55620098114 сек.

